# Cannot start VirtualBox VM after Ubuntu Server Updates

Tags: virtualbox

After installing Ubuntu Server updates I can no longer launch my VM with Virtualbox. Prior to the updates VirtualBox was working fine.

**Ubuntu version:**

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

**Virtualbox version:**

- virtualbox-6.1                 6.1.4-136177~Ubuntu~bionic  amd64 
  Oracle VM VirtualBox
- virtualbox-dkms 5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms

dpkg -l | grep virtualbox:

> rc  virtualbox                             5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1
>   amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
>
> rc  virtualbox-4.3                         4.3.40-110317~Ubuntu~raring
>   amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
>
> ii  virtualbox-6.1                         6.1.4-136177~Ubuntu~bionic 
>   amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
>
> ii  virtualbox-dkms                        5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1
>   all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for
>   dkms
>
> rc  virtualbox-qt                          5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1
>   amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface

When I try to launch my vm with:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "Ubuntu-Server-PiHole-18.04"
```

I get:

> VBoxHeadless: Error -1912 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
>   VBoxHeadless: RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912
>
> VBoxHeadless: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

I then tried to reinstall VirtualBox with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

The output looks like so:

> Deleting module version: 5.2.34 completely from the DKMS tree.
>
> Done.
>
> Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) over (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
>
> Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
>
> Loading new virtualbox-5.2.34 DKMS files...
>
> Building for 4.15.0-91-generic
>
> Building initial module for 4.15.0-91-generic.
>
> Done.

Do I have a mismatch between the VirtualBox version and the VirtualBox-dkms version?

How can I best resolve this? (I do have the Virtualbox repo already added to my sources list: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease )

Comment: I do not know if this is the solution, but the steps you list when you tried to reinstall virtualbox may not be complete. Don't you need to do `virtualbox-6.1` as well as `virtualbox-dkms` if you really want to reinstall the whole thing? If it gets reinstalled as a dependency, my apologies.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I actually ran into other problems trying to remove virtualbox-6.1 but finally managed. You got me on the right track.

Comment: I am glad you got it sorted.